# The link to meta is not consist in the web and mobile view

Tags: feature-request, footer, full-site

In each site's [Participate In Meta - Privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) page, under **Where is meta?** section the description is starting as **There is a link to meta in the footer of every page**.....

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: The link to meta is not consist in the web and mobile view]

In the full site view of footer clicking on the **feedback** it will redirect to meta site.
But in the mobile view, **meta** link is still used to redirect the meta site.
<del>Updating the **meta** to **feedback** in the footer of mobile view will make some consistence.</del>

**Edit:**
Updating the **feedback** to **meta** in the footer of the full-site view, will make it consistence.

Comment: But I would never look for "meta" under "feedback"... I'd rather "meta" was a bare link... otherwise, the statement "there is a link to meta in the footer of every page" is a lie. I mean, I get that "feedback" is more general and it makes sense to call it that to get people to find it... but, as someone who uses meta, I would not equate "feedback" to mean "take me to meta".