# Where is the meta of Software Quality Assurance & Testing?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

I would like to ask if someone could create a tmap tag, but there is no meta site for [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I see it: https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: normally there is a meta button that could be clicked

Comment: I see it under the "Help" menu. Where are you looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three permanent links from any page in the main site to Meta.

1. Go to [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/) and press the Stack Exchange link above:

> [image]

You'll find a link to Meta:

> [image]

This will drive you to [Software Quality Assurance & Testing **Meta**](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/).

2. On the top bar, click on *Help*:

> [image]

You'll see the link to *Meta* just after the *Help Center*.

3. In the footer, under the name *feedback*:

> [image]

Comment: There are two more ways: Help --> Meta, and in footer. Care to add those as well to the answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard you are right. Added, thanks! The _feedback_ link is not very indicative on what is linking to, though :D

Comment: By the way, my screen shots get randomly some blueish tone, I don't know why. Feel free to update them if it bothers your eyes!

Comment: All good, as for "feedback" you're right, might be worth starting a feature request asking to change it, e.g. to "meta" or at least add a tooltip there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Hope you are talking [about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274616/312043) !

Comment: @Arulkumar lol, yes indeed! :)